# Asp send parameter character problem

Tags: asp.net

i send parameter usinge Response.Redirect() to anotherpage

Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/mypage.aspx?value=" + myvalue))

but myvalue has some invalid characters like ö,ü and i can't receive the parameter correct.

has anyone idea, how can i get it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a server.UrlEncode it should take care of it for you.  i.e.

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/mypage.aspx?value={0}", Server.UrlEncode(myvalue)))
```

Then before you consume it on the other side you would have to decode it.

```
String myvalue = Server.UrlDecode(Request["value"])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
it didn't work but the problem is something else
the character seems correct on the page but when i get it to my variable it is defect. and so i can not encode the right string

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't still find the problem.

Charset is utf-8 and everything seems ok on the page. but when i read data from asp Grid
using gridView.SelectedRow.Cells(index).Text i can not get the correct value. it seems on grid correct but when i read, gridView.SelectedRow.Cells(index).Text value doesn't display utf-8 characters. how should i read it from grid else?

EDIT (originally this was a comment to this answer where nobody sees it):

solved! i don't know why, but i used to decode the data i read from grid using Server.HtmlDecode(myvalue) to get the data correctly